# How to extract week number as week format in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

I have a column of timestamp ...

I'm going to use OBIEE and the user told me that need graphics per day, week and month...

Of the timestamp I'm extracting day, and month ... like this :

```
--day
select to_char(register_dt, 'DAY DD') as "Day"
from XX;

--by week

--by month
select to_char(register_dt, 'FMMONTH') as "Month"
from XX;
```

I found

```
select to_char( register_dt, 'WW' ) as "Week"
from XX;
```

but that only give me the number of the week like 36 etc, Can anybody help me to figure it out how to display a week range? like

I mean this is Sept 6, like

1 / Sept / 7

8 / Sept / 14

etc.. etc..

Please !!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can truncate the `date` to the beginning of the prior week and then manipulate that.  So, for example, you can run something like

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'W') as first_of_week, 
       trunc( sysdate + 7, 'W' ) - 1 as last_of_week,
       to_char( trunc(sysdate, 'W'), 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) || ' to ' ||
         to_char( trunc( sysdate + 7, 'W' ) - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) as week_range
  from dual
```

to get a string `01-SEP-2013 to 07-SEP-2013` as the `week_range`

Comment: Amazing!, that's exactly what I need, thank you very much for your time! I'll accept the question in 2 minutes, it doesn't let me now...
Have a great day.

Comment: Hey Justin, Can u help me with other problem?

Comment: @Raf0c - What "other problem"?

Comment: Im trying to add the results of the queries in other columns, I mean columns like month, day, weeks
 and if i do
SELECT 
      estate_id,muni_id,(select to_char(register_dt, 'FMMONTH') from XX) as month
FROM 
      YY 
inner join 
      XX
ON
      YY.case_idlab = XX.case_idlab;
it says 
ORA-01427: la subconsulta de una sola fila devuelve más de una fila
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
 :(

Comment: I tried
SELECT 
  other_columns, (select to_char(register_dt, 'DAY DD') from XX) as Dy
from YY;
I want in the result columns from YY and at the end the column Dy from the date
I got some values that I can make the join, it can be done with the join and the full date, but with the "select to_char bla bla the modification "I cant join them